# Error "NOT A JSON REQUEST" when trying to create a GCM Notification Key in GAS

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create a User Notification group on Google Cloud Messaging using a Google Apps Script server.  I'm following directions here:http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html

I'm getting the following error:

> Request failed for https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification
>   returned code 400. Truncated server response:
>   {"error":"NOT_A_JSON_REQUEST"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to
>   examine full response) (line 86, file "Code")

```
function SetUserNotification(data) {
  var url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification";
  var apiKey = "<MyApiKey>";
  var projectID = "<MyProjectId>";
  var registrationId = data[2];

  var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "project_id": projectID,
      "Authorization": "key=" + apiKey
    };
  var payload = { 
      "operation": "create",
      "notification_key_name": "ST-User" + data[3],
      "registration_ids": registrationId
   };
    var params = {
      headers: headers,
      method: "post",
      payload: payload
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log("response = " + response.getContentText());
  return {message: "send completed: " + response.getContentText()};
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?  I can't find any examples of creating a notification key online, just what seems to be incomplete instructions.

Update: Here's the execution transcript from the fetch function. Note line 87 is the fetch call.

> [15-01-25 21:55:11:877 EST]
>   UrlFetchApp.fetch([https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification,
>   {headers={Authorization=key=MYAUTHKEY, project_id=MYPROJID,
>   Content-Type=application/json},
>   payload={"operation":"create","notification_key_name":"ST-User1","registration_ids":"[abcdefgblahblah]"},
>   method=post}]) [0.015 seconds]
>
> [15-01-25 21:55:11:879 EST] Execution failed: Request failed for
>   https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification returned code 400.
>   Truncated server response: {"error":"NOT_A_JSON_REQUEST"} (use
>   muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 87, file
>   "Code") [0.019 seconds total runtime]

Comment: In the documentation, "registration_ids" takes an array.  You aren't formatting the data as an array.  I'm not saying that's the issue, but it might be worth trying.  "Hard code" it first to see if it makes a different.  `"registration_ids": ["4"]`

Comment: Sandy, I've tried that and could not get it working. I'll look at fixing the payload variable later today to see if that's it.

Comment: Corrected var, didn't work. You can see in my update that registration_ids comes through as an array.

Comment: I'd put `headers`, `method` and `payload` in double quotes, and see if that makes a difference.  `"headers": headers, etc`

Answer (score 2):

You need to to convert your payload to JSON, as this isn't done automatically.  Do this using the javascript's built in JSON object as shown below.

Additionally, you cannot override the content-type header via the Headers parameter as you have in your code.  You must use the separate contentType parameter instead.

```
var headers = {
  "project_id": projectID,
  "Authorization": "key=" + apiKey
};

var params = {
  headers: headers,
  method: "post",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
};
```

See advanced parameters section here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)

and JSON documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Methods

Comment: Depending on what data[2] and data[3] contain that already looks like valid JSON.

Comment: It's a valid Javascript Object, but it's not the JSON representation of that object.  JSON.stringify() will return the string representation of that object in JSON, which is what the payload needs to be in this case.

Comment: Tried it but I get the same error. data[2] and data[3] are just strings representing a unique user code and the device registrationId.  I've updated the question with more detail on what is being sent

Comment: AH, sorry, I missed another change needed, you can't specify the Content-Type header that way, you need to pass it as it's own parameter.  Updating my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I found out!!!

```js
function registerForKey(){
  var url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification";
  var headers = {"content-type": "application/json","project_id": proj,    "Authorization": "key=" + api  };
  var request = {"operation": "create",   "notification_key_name": groupname,   "registration_ids": [id]};
  var pay = JSON.stringify(request);

  var params = {"headers": headers,"method": "POST",  "payload": pay }; 
  var respo = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params)
  
  Logger.log(respo);
  
  
  }
```

Please note
a)in headers how the content type has to be written, with all minuscule and the trait between;
b) payload needs to be stringified;
c) insert a real id as request id, otherwise it will give an error!

So just copy this snippet, insert all the variables needed, run and then pres CTRL+Enter and...voila'! :)

Enjoy :D